# GAM with "gp" smoother: predict at new locations

Tags: r, regression, gam, mgcv, kriging

I am using the following geoadditive model

```
library(gamair)
library(mgcv)

data(mack)    
mack$log.net.area <- log(mack$net.area)

gm2 <- gam(egg.count ~ s(lon,lat,bs="gp",k=100,m=c(2,10,1)) +
                       s(I(b.depth^.5)) +
                       s(c.dist) +
                       s(temp.20m) +
                       offset(log.net.area),
                       data = mack, family = tw, method = "REML")
```

How can I use it to predict the value of `egg.count` at new locations `(lon/lat)` where I don't have covariate data, as in `kriging`?

For example say I want to predict `egg.count` at these new locations

```
    lon lat
1  -3.00  44
4  -2.75  44
7  -2.50  44
10 -2.25  44
13 -2.00  44
16 -1.75  44
```

but here I don't know the values of the covariates (`b.depth`, `c.dist`, `temp.20m`, `log.net.area`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`predict` still requires all variables used in your model to be presented in `newdata`, but you can pass in some arbitrary values, like `0`s, to those covariates you don't have, then use `type = "terms"` and `terms = name_of_the_wanted_smooth_term` to proceed. Use

```
sapply(gm2$smooth, "[[", "label")
#[1] "s(lon,lat)"        "s(I(b.depth^0.5))" "s(c.dist)"        
#[4] "s(temp.20m)"
```

to check what smooth terms are in your model.

```
## new spatial locations to predict
newdat <- read.table(text = "lon lat
                             1  -3.00  44
                             4  -2.75  44
                             7  -2.50  44
                             10 -2.25  44
                             13 -2.00  44
                             16 -1.75  44")

## "garbage" values, just to pass the variable names checking in `predict.gam`
newdat[c("b.depth", "c.dist", "temp.20m", "log.net.area")] <- 0

## prediction on the link scale
pred_link <- predict(gm2, newdata = newdat, type = "terms", terms = "s(lon,lat)")
#   s(lon,lat)
#1  -1.9881967
#4  -1.9137971
#7  -1.6365945
#10 -1.1247837
#13 -0.7910023
#16 -0.7234683
#attr(,"constant")
#(Intercept) 
#   2.553535 

## simplify to vector
pred_link <- attr(pred_link, "constant") + rowSums(pred_link)
#[1] 0.5653381 0.6397377 0.9169403 1.4287511 1.7625325 1.8300665

## prediction on the response scale
pred_response <- gm2$family$linkinv(pred_link)
#[1] 1.760043 1.895983 2.501625 4.173484 5.827176 6.234301
```

---

I don't normally use `predict.gam` if I want to do prediction for a specific smooth term. The logic of `predict.gam` is to do prediction for all terms first, that is, the same as your doing `type = "terms"`. Then

- if `type = "link"`, do a `rowSums` on all term-wise predictions plus an intercept (possibly with `offset`);
- if `type = "terms"`, and `"terms"` or `"exclude"` are unspecified, return the result as it is;
- if `type = "terms"` and you have specified `"terms"` and / or `"exclude"`, some post-process is done to drop terms you don't want and only give you those you want.

So, `predict.gam` will always do computation for all terms, even if you just want a single term.

Knowing the inefficiency behind this, this is what I will do:

```
sm <- gm2$smooth[[1]]  ## extract smooth construction info for `s(lon,lat)`
Xp <- PredictMat(sm, newdat)  ## predictor matrix
b <- gm2$coefficients[with(sm, first.para:last.para)]  ## coefficients for this term
pred_link <- c(Xp %*% b) + gm2$coef[[1]]  ## this term + intercept
#[1] 0.5653381 0.6397377 0.9169403 1.4287511 1.7625325 1.8300665
pred_response <- gm2$family$linkinv(pred_link)
#[1] 1.760043 1.895983 2.501625 4.173484 5.827176 6.234301
```

You see, we get the same result.

---

> Won't the result depend the way on the value assigned to the covariates (here 0)?

Some garbage prediction will be made at those garbage values, but `predict.gam` discards them in the end.

> Thanks, you are right. I am not totally sure to understand why then there is the option to add the covariates values at new locations.

Code maintenance is, as far as I feel, very difficult for a big package like `mgcv`. The code needs be changed significantly if you want it to suit every user's need. Obviously the `predict.gam` logic as I described here will be inefficient when people, like you, just want it to predict a certain smooth. And in theory if this is the case, variable names checking in `newdata` can ignore those terms not wanted by users. But, that requires significant change of `predict.gam`, and could potentially introduce many bugs due to code changes. Furthermore, you have to submit a changelog to CRAN, and CRAN may just not be happy to see this drastic change.

Simon once shared his feelings: *there are many people telling me, I should write `mgcv` as this or as that, but I simply can't*. Yeah, give some sympathy to a package author / maintainer like him.

---

> Thanks for the update answer. However, I don't understand why the predictions don't depend on the values of the covariates at the new locations.

It will depend if you provide covariates values for `b.depth`, `c.dist`, `temp.20m`, `log.net.area`. But since you don't have them at new locations, the prediction is just to assume these effects to be `0`.

> OK thanks I see now! So would it be correct to say that in the absence of covariate values at new locations I am only predicting the response from the spatial autocorrelation of the residuals?

You are only predicting the spatial field / smooth. In GAM approach the spatial field is modeled as part of mean, not variance-covariance (as in kriging), so I think your use of "residuals" is not correct here.

> Yes, you are right. Just to understand what this code does: would it be correct to say that I am predicting how the response changes over space but not its actual values at the new locations (since for that I would need the values of the covariates at these locations)?

Correct. You can try `predict.gam` with or without `terms = "s(lon,lat)"` to help you digest the output. See how it changes when you vary garbage values passed to other covariates.

```
## a possible set of garbage values for covariates
newdat[c("b.depth", "c.dist", "temp.20m", "log.net.area")] <- 0

predict(gm2, newdat, type = "terms")
#   s(lon,lat) s(I(b.depth^0.5)) s(c.dist) s(temp.20m)
#1  -1.9881967          -1.05514 0.4739174   -1.466549
#4  -1.9137971          -1.05514 0.4739174   -1.466549
#7  -1.6365945          -1.05514 0.4739174   -1.466549
#10 -1.1247837          -1.05514 0.4739174   -1.466549
#13 -0.7910023          -1.05514 0.4739174   -1.466549
#16 -0.7234683          -1.05514 0.4739174   -1.466549
#attr(,"constant")
#(Intercept) 
#   2.553535 

predict(gm2, newdat, type = "terms", terms = "s(lon,lat)")
#   s(lon,lat)
#1  -1.9881967
#4  -1.9137971
#7  -1.6365945
#10 -1.1247837
#13 -0.7910023
#16 -0.7234683
#attr(,"constant")
#(Intercept) 
#   2.553535
```

---

```
## another possible set of garbage values for covariates
newdat[c("b.depth", "c.dist", "temp.20m", "log.net.area")] <- 1
#   s(lon,lat) s(I(b.depth^0.5))  s(c.dist) s(temp.20m)
#1  -1.9881967        -0.9858522 -0.3749018   -1.269878
#4  -1.9137971        -0.9858522 -0.3749018   -1.269878
#7  -1.6365945        -0.9858522 -0.3749018   -1.269878
#10 -1.1247837        -0.9858522 -0.3749018   -1.269878
#13 -0.7910023        -0.9858522 -0.3749018   -1.269878
#16 -0.7234683        -0.9858522 -0.3749018   -1.269878
#attr(,"constant")
#(Intercept) 
#   2.553535 

predict(gm2, newdat, type = "terms", terms = "s(lon,lat)")
#   s(lon,lat)
#1  -1.9881967
#4  -1.9137971
#7  -1.6365945
#10 -1.1247837
#13 -0.7910023
#16 -0.7234683
#attr(,"constant")
#(Intercept) 
#   2.553535
```