# mgcv: How to use 'exclude' argument in predict.gam?

Tags: r, regression, predict, gam, mgcv

I have a model structured as follows, and I would like to extract the predicted values while ignoring the random effect. As specified in `?predict.gam` and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131106/predicting-with-random-effects-in-mgcv-gam), I am using the `exclude` argument, but I am getting an error. Where is my mistake?

```
dt <- data.frame(n1 = runif(500, min=0, max=1),
             n2 = rep(1:10,50), 
             n3 = runif(500, min=0, max=2),
             n4 = runif(500, min=0, max=2),
             c1 = factor(rep(c("X","Y"),250)),
             c2 = factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 100)))

mod = gam(n1 ~ 
           s(n2, n3, n4, by=c1) +
           s(c2, bs="re"),
         data=dt)

newd=data.table(expand.grid(n1=seq(min(dt$n1), max(dt$n1), 0.5), 
                        n2=1:10,
                        n3=seq(min(dt$n3), max(dt$n3), 0.5),
                        n4=seq(min(dt$n4), max(dt$n4), 0.5),
                        c1=c("X", "Y")))
newd$pred <- predict.gam(mod, newd, exclude = "s(c2)")

In predict.gam(mod, newd, exclude = "s(c2)"): not all required variables have been supplied in  newdata!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exclude` does not work in the way as you assumed. You still need to provide all variables in your `newd` for `predict.gam`. See my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51635487/4891738) for what is behind `predict.gam`.

Here is what you need to do:

```
## pad newd with an arbitrary value for variable c2
newd$c2 <- "a"
## termwise prediction
pt <- predict.gam(mod, newd, type = "terms", exclude = "s(c2)")
## linear predictor without random effect
lp_no_c2 <- rowSums(pt) + attr(pt, "constant")
```

Comment: if I were to exclude multiple variables, how would I do it - like this? `pt <- predict.gam(mod, newd, type = "terms", exclude =c( "s(c2)", s(n4)))`

Comment: ah, ok, so I would have to specify the whole term: `pt <- predict.gam(mod, newd, type = "terms", exclude =c( "s(c2)", "s(n2, n3, n4)"))` (ignoring the fact that for this example model then there would be not predictor left)

Comment: @lueromat Use `sapply(mod$smooth, “[[”,  “label”)` to see what terms are in the model. Note that factor “by” has a smooth for each factor level, so you will see for example `s(n2,n3,n4):c1X` for level “X” of `c1`.