# Changing predicted values to response scale after predict() function, not via type = "response"

Tags: r, predict, gam

Working in R. I'm having trouble with calculating my predicted values to the response scale when I have to exclude a random effect from the prediction. By excluding the random effect from the prediction, I need to specify `type = "terms"`, hereby making it impossible to include the `type = "response"` argument. Is there a way of recalculating the predicted values to the response scale (beta regression)? Or is it possible to both specify the exclusion of `Area` and `type = "response"` in the `predict` function? Please see my code below.

```
str(data_re)
# 'data.frame': 35 obs. of  17 variables:
# $ ProportionBirdsScavenging: num  0.6619 0.4062 0.6943 0.0143 0.0143 ...
# $ OverheadCover            : num  0.7 0.671 0.679 0.79 0.62 ...
# $ Area                     : Factor w/ 6 levels "Hamert","KempenBroek",..: 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
# $ pointWeight              : int  3 233 10 89 4 22 44 99 89 17 ...

mygam <- mgcv::gam(ProportionBirdsScavenging ~ OverheadCover + s(Area, bs="re"), family=betar(link="logit"), data = data_re, weights = pointWeight)
new.xgam <- expand.grid(OverheadCover = seq(0, 1, length.out = 1000))
new.xgam$Area <- "a" # pad new.xgam with an arbitrary value for variable Area -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411851/mgcv-how-to-use-exclude-argument-in-predict-gam
new.ygam <- predict.gam(mygam, newdata = new.xgam, type = "terms", exclude = "s(Area)") # Because I have to specify type = "terms", I can't specify type = "response".
new.ygam <- data.frame(new.ygam)

head(new.ygam) # not on the response scale (0,1)
# OverheadCover
# 1   0.000000000
# 2  -0.004390776
# 3  -0.008781551
# 4  -0.013172327
# 5  -0.017563103
# 6  -0.021953878
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misreading the documentation for the argument `exclude`:

> exclude: if `type=="terms"` or `type="iterms"` then terms (smooth or
>             parametric) named in this array will not be returned.
>             **Otherwise** any smooth terms named in this array will be set to
>             zero.  If `NULL` then no terms are excluded. Note that this
>             is the term names as it appears in the model summary, see
>             example. You can avoid providing the covariates for the
>             excluded terms by setting `newdata.guaranteed=TRUE`, which
>             will avoid all checks on `newdata`.

(emphasis mine).

You can use `type = "response", exclude = "s(Area)")` and the random effect should be ignored. You do have to pass in to `newdata` some values for `Area` otherwise this won't work; just set the `Area` column in the `newdata` to be all the first level of `Area`.

If you are *very careful* you can avoid passing in the ranef variable too. If you are sure that what you pass to `newdata` is a correctly specified set of variables for the model, then you can leave out `Area` and pass `newdata.guaranteed = TRUE` to `predict()` to stop `predict()` from checking that you have correctly passed all variables needed for the model.

See the example in `?mgcv::random.effects` for both types of behaviour.