# Predicted SE vary from ggeffects::ggpredict - what am I doing wrong? 'Object not found' for predict function

Tags: r, prediction, confidence-interval

I am running an analysis in r on the effect of canopy cover (`OverheadCover`, proportion bounded by 0,1) and the number of carcasses placed on the same location (`CarcassNumber`, factor with 2 levels) on the proportion of carrion eaten by birds (`ProportionBirdsScavenging`, proportion bounded by 0,1). I plotted this interaction by modelling the effect of `OverheadCover` on `ProportionBirdsScavenging` for the separate values of `CarcassNumber`, then plotting it in the same graph. Having done this, I saw discrepancies in the SE's calculated by `plot_model(glmm_interaction, type = "int")` and the SE's I calculated. Here started an investigation. This journey led me through the source codes of `plot_model`, `plot_type_int`, `ggpredict` and stopped with `ggpredict_helper`. I did unfortunately not find the calculation of SE's, but I found proof of the difference in SE's. I always was pretty confident that I calculated my SE's correctly, but now I'm not so sure anymore. Please see my code below.

```r
#rm(list = ls())

library(glmmTMB)
library(dplyr)

data_both <- data.frame(ProportionBirdsScavenging = c(0.406192519926425, 0.871428571428571, 0.452995391705069, 0.484821428571429, 0.795866569978245, 0.985714285714286, 0.208571428571429, 0.573982970671712, 0.694285714285714, 0.930204081632653, 0.0483709273182957, 0.0142857142857143, 0.661904761904762, 0.985714285714286, 0.0142857142857143, 0.0142857142857143),
                        pointWeight = c(233, 17, 341, 128, 394, 46, 5, 302, 10, 35, 57, 39, 12, 229, 28, 116),
                        OverheadCover = c(0.671, 0.04, 0.46, 0.65, 0.02, 0, 0.8975, 0.585, 0.6795, 0.0418, 0.5995, 0.6545, 0.02, 0, 0.92, 0.585),
                        CarcassNumber = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)),
                        Area = c("Hamert", "KempenBroek", "KempenBroek", "KempenBroek", "Markiezaat", "Markiezaat", "Meinweg", "Valkenhorst", "Hamert", "KempenBroek", "KempenBroek", "KempenBroek", "Markiezaat", "Markiezaat", "Meinweg", "Valkenhorst"))
data_both$pointWeight_scaled <- scales::rescale(data_both$pointWeight, to = c(0.0001,1)) # rescale weights

glmm_interaction <- glmmTMB(ProportionBirdsScavenging ~ OverheadCover * CarcassNumber + (1|Area), data = data_both, beta_family(link = "logit"), weights = pointWeight_scaled)
ggeffects::ggpredict(glmm_interaction, terms = c("OverheadCover", "CarcassNumber [1:2]")) # SE's calculated by r

# Calculate the SE's for CarcassNumber 1
df_first_carcasses <- filter(data_both, CarcassNumber == 1) # create df with only first carcasses
myglmm <- glmmTMB(ProportionBirdsScavenging ~ OverheadCover, data = df_first_carcasses, beta_family(link = "logit"), weights = pointWeight_scaled)
new.xglmm <- expand.grid(OverheadCover = seq(min(data_both$OverheadCover), max(data_both$OverheadCover), length.out = 1000)) %>%
  mutate(Area = "Hamert", pointWeight_scaled = 1) # pad new.xglmm with an arbitrary value for Area and pointWeight_scaled, then exclude them in predict, otherwise error -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411851/mgcv-how-to-use-exclude-argument-in-predict-gam
new.yglmm <- data.frame(predict(myglmm, new.xglmm, type = "link", exclude = c("Area","pointWeight_scaled"), se.fit = TRUE)) %>% # exclude Area and pointWeight_scaled from the prediction
  mutate(ProportionBirdsScavenging = plogis(fit)) %>% # calculate the ProportionBirdsScavenging on response scale
  rename(SE.untransformed = se.fit, untransformed.predictions = fit)
addTheseglmm1 <- mutate(data.frame(new.xglmm, new.yglmm), # calculate the lwr and upr bounds using the untransformed predictions and SE, then transformed to probability
                        lwr = plogis(untransformed.predictions - SE.untransformed),
                        upr = plogis(untransformed.predictions + SE.untransformed))
addTheseglmm1[c(1,45,501,653,707,1000),c(1,6,5)] # compare my SE's to the ggpredict SE's

#  calculated by ggpredict   >   manually calculated
#    x | Predicted |   SE |  >      SE.untransformed
# -------------------------  >   -------------------
# 0.00 |      0.82 | 0.44 |  >                  0.43
# 0.04 |      0.80 | 0.41 |  >                  0.40
# 0.46 |      0.56 | 0.22 |  >                  0.21
# 0.60 |      0.47 | 0.26 |  >                  0.25
# 0.65 |      0.44 | 0.29 |  >                  0.28
# 0.92 |      0.28 | 0.47 |  >                  0.46
#  ( CarcassNumber = 1 )

# Same for CarcassNumber 2
df_second_carcasses <- filter(data_both, CarcassNumber == 2) # create df with only second carcasses
myglmm <- glmmTMB(ProportionBirdsScavenging ~ OverheadCover, data = df_second_carcasses, beta_family(link = "logit"), weights = pointWeight_scaled)
new.xglmm <- expand.grid(OverheadCover = seq(min(data_both$OverheadCover), max(data_both$OverheadCover), length.out = 1000)) %>%
  mutate(Area = "Hamert", pointWeight_scaled = 1) 
new.yglmm <- data.frame(predict(myglmm, new.xglmm, type = "link", exclude = c("Area","pointWeight_scaled"), se.fit = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(ProportionBirdsScavenging = plogis(fit)) %>%
  rename(SE.untransformed = se.fit, untransformed.predictions = fit)
addTheseglmm2 <- mutate(data.frame(new.xglmm, new.yglmm),
                        lwr = plogis(untransformed.predictions - SE.untransformed),
                        upr = plogis(untransformed.predictions + SE.untransformed))

addTheseglmm2[c(1,45,501,653,707,1000),c(1,6,5)]

#  calculated by ggpredict   >   manually calculated
#    x | Predicted |   SE |  >      SE.untransformed
# -------------------------  >   -------------------
# 0.00 |      0.96 | 1.01 |  >                  1.21
# 0.04 |      0.95 | 0.94 |  >                  1.10
# 0.46 |      0.16 | 0.86 |  >                  0.96
# 0.60 |      0.04 | 1.11 |  >                  1.32
# 0.65 |      0.02 | 1.22 |  >                  1.46
# 0.92 |      0.00 | 1.83 |  >                  2.31
#  ( CarcassNumber = 2 )
```

The differences are most visible for `CarcassNumber` 2. Is my calculation incorrect? I suspect that this discrepancy might have to do with the including and excluding of `pointWeight_scaled` in the `predict` function. If I don't do this, it returns me an error saying `Error in eval(extras, data, env) : object 'pointWeight_scaled' not found`. Is this a common problem? I read here that including and then excluding it resolves the issue [mgcv: How to use 'exclude' argument in predict.gam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411851/mgcv-how-to-use-exclude-argument-in-predict-gam). Is this not the proper way?

I hope that someone can shed some light on this problem.

Comment: At first glace it seems like `ggeffects::ggpredict` is using your full model, but you are calculating SE's on a reduced model.

Comment: Details are in `ggeffects:::get_predictions_glmmTMB`, though it may take some effort to parse out what is happening.

Comment: @ Axeman yes I am calculating SE's on a reduced model. I don't see how to otherwise produce these models and SE's separate for each value of ```CarcassNumber```. Basically, I'm trying to reproduce ```sjPlot::plot_model(glmm_interaction, type = "int", ci.lvl = 0.682)```, but then with ```ggplot```.  I'll have a look at ```ggeffects:::get_predictions_glmmTMB```

Answer (score 1):

hm, when I run your example, I get the same results as you expect:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(ggeffects)

data_both <- data.frame(ProportionBirdsScavenging = c(0.406192519926425, 0.871428571428571, 0.452995391705069, 0.484821428571429, 0.795866569978245, 0.985714285714286, 0.208571428571429, 0.573982970671712, 0.694285714285714, 0.930204081632653, 0.0483709273182957, 0.0142857142857143, 0.661904761904762, 0.985714285714286, 0.0142857142857143, 0.0142857142857143),
                        pointWeight = c(233, 17, 341, 128, 394, 46, 5, 302, 10, 35, 57, 39, 12, 229, 28, 116),
                        OverheadCover = c(0.671, 0.04, 0.46, 0.65, 0.02, 0, 0.8975, 0.585, 0.6795, 0.0418, 0.5995, 0.6545, 0.02, 0, 0.92, 0.585),
                        CarcassNumber = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)),
                        Area = c("Hamert", "KempenBroek", "KempenBroek", "KempenBroek", "Markiezaat", "Markiezaat", "Meinweg", "Valkenhorst", "Hamert", "KempenBroek", "KempenBroek", "KempenBroek", "Markiezaat", "Markiezaat", "Meinweg", "Valkenhorst"))
data_both$pointWeight_scaled <- scales::rescale(data_both$pointWeight, to = c(0.0001,1)) # rescale weights

df_second_carcasses <- dplyr::filter(data_both, CarcassNumber == 2) # create df with only second carcasses
m <- glmmTMB(ProportionBirdsScavenging ~ OverheadCover, data = df_second_carcasses, beta_family(link = "logit"), weights = pointWeight_scaled)

ggpredict(m, "OverheadCover")
#> 
#> # Predicted values of ProportionBirdsScavenging
#> # x = OverheadCover
#> 
#>    x | Predicted |   SE |       95% CI
#> --------------------------------------
#> 0.00 |      0.96 | 1.21 | [0.70, 1.00]
#> 0.02 |      0.95 | 1.16 | [0.67, 0.99]
#> 0.04 |      0.94 | 1.10 | [0.65, 0.99]
#> 0.58 |      0.05 | 1.27 | [0.00, 0.40]
#> 0.60 |      0.04 | 1.31 | [0.00, 0.38]
#> 0.65 |      0.03 | 1.47 | [0.00, 0.32]
#> 0.68 |      0.02 | 1.55 | [0.00, 0.30]
#> 0.92 |      0.00 | 2.31 | [0.00, 0.13]
#> Standard errors are on link-scale (untransformed).
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

A reason might be that glmmTMB was just updated on CRAN and has the `re.form`-argument enabled in `predict()`. I have included this in the very latest commit on [GitHub](https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects) (i.e. now `predict()` in *ggeffects* for *glmmTMB* models also use the `re.form` argument), so maybe you get identical results when you update *ggeffects* from GitHub?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I tried ```library(devtools)```
```install_github("strengejacke/ggeffects")```, but the package installation failed. As I'm new with updating packages from GitHub, can you explain how can I do this correctly?

Comment: If you provide some more details about the errors you get, I can probably help. Else, I've uploaded the source and binary version to GitHub, which you can install directly from R/RStudio: https://github.com/strengejacke/ggeffects/releases/tag/0.14.1.1

Comment: Note that you need to update glmmTMB to version 1.0 from CRAN